# TouchEvent on Widget without creating an activity

Tags: android, widget

I want to do some calculating after touch-Event on my widget.
Is there a possibility to do this without starting an activity? My problem is that i have to register an onClickPendingIntent to the touch-action....

There is an annoying visual response with my solution: screen flashes to black and reappears to homescreen.

this is in the widget-provider:

```
Intent doit_intent = new Intent(context, DoItActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
           PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, doit_intent, 0);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.main_widget, pendingIntent);
```

DoItActivity.class

```
public class DoItActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //do some static function calls

    finish();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `PendingIntent` that does not start an activity, then. Use `getService()` or `getBroadcast()` instead of `getActivity()`.

Comment: @LeoMelo: "How can I implement a PendingIntent that does not start an activity?" -- call `getService()` instead of `getActivity()` to create a `PendingIntent` that will start a service. Call `getBroadcast()` instead of `getActivity()` to create a `PendingIntent` that will send a broadcast.

Comment: @LeoMelo: You cannot use `getService()` or `getBroadcast()` to start an activity. You use `getService()` to start a `Service`. You use `getBroadcast()` to start a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. As I don´t know how to implement this BroadcastReceiver I´ll  try to learn it first. Cause I have the same issue, same scenario. But when I change to PendingIntent.getBroadcast() and click my widget nothing happens.